# limit of function at $x \rightarrow 2$

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring, absolute-value

ok, so this is a very basic question,

i'm trying to find the limit of the following function at $x \rightarrow 2$:

$|x^2 + 3x + 2| / (x^2 - 4)$

what i had previously done was simply plug in 2 for the LHL and the RHL, and write them off as negative infinite and positive infinite, respectively.

now im wondering, is there a smarter way to simplify this/get to the answer? i can break everything down to get $(x + 2)(x + 1) / (x + 2)(x - 2)$.

where would the negative sign from the absolute value come in? can i straight up cancel out the $(x + 2)$ terms from the numerator and denominator?

basically, my question is how do i get to the answer algebraically (which i'm pretty sure is what i am supposed to do)?

Comment: but $2^2+3\cdot 2+2=12\ne 0$ thus the limit doesn't exist

Comment: If $x \neq -2$ you can cancel the $x+2$ terms. Then notice that the numerator has a limit 3 (as $x \to 2$) whereas the numerator is a tiny positive or negative number.

Comment: i know, what i dont understand is how to get to the point where i can show LHL != RHL algebraically. like, what do i do with the negative sign when i open the absolute value? do i only use it when calculating for the LHL? and if so, why?

Comment: copper.hat, what i dont get is where did the absolute value's negative sign go? shouldn't there be one after opening the absolute value? and if i do add one, that messes up what i can cancel out

Comment: is that $$x \rightarrow -2$$?

Comment: @Alt, no its x -> 2

Comment: In principle we never plug in, we examine the behaviour of the function **near** $x=2$.

Comment: @Rafflesia arnoldii, instead of editing my title, why don't you try answering the question?!

Comment: pleaseeeeeeeeeeeee people its really not that hard of a question

Comment: @Rafflesia arnoldii, im begging you, please try the question, i promise ill change the title as soon as someone gives a satisfactory explanation

Answer (score 1):

The limit is:

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\left|x^2+3x+2\right|}{x^2-4}$$

Since the denominator $=0$ when $x=2$, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: right, i got that, i dont get how to analytically show that LHL is not equal to RHL, like when i break down the absolute value, what happens to the negative sign?

Comment: You don't need to analyze the absolute value. If the limit was $x\to -2$ instead of $x\to 2$, it would make a difference. The value exists for the numerator as $x\to 2$, but equals $0$ for the denominator. Therefore, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: i understand that, but can you explain how i could see that by finding the LHL and the RHL? how would i analytically find them?

Comment: Why would you need to? as $x \to 2^{-}$ and $x \to 2^{+}$ they both converge to the same value. Use a graph or arbitrary values to show this if you cannot see it.

Comment: umm they obviously dont, or the limit would exist at x = 2, which you said yourself it doesn't. Besides, could you please just answer the question? as a matter of fact, could anyone reading this answer the question please?

Comment: As $x$ approaches two from the left, you have $\approx12$ divided by a very small negative number. How about from the right?

Comment: it would be 12 divided by a very small positive number. so, im guessing you're going to say that LHL is negative infinite and RHL is positive infinite, and that's why there is no limit at x = 2, right? its just, what im asking is if there is any way to open the absolute value, and then analytically find the limit

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "open the absolute value" and "analytically?" When you have a rational function and you see something like "$\frac{12}{0}$," you have a non-existent limit, and it's just a matter of determining whether you can classify it as a positive infinite limit, a negative infinite limit, or neither.